# How to prevent from the value error which is appeared while getting data from firestore database in Python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, valueerror, kivymd

I'm using `firebase firestore` database for my `KivyMD` project. In the program when a button is pressed the data should be saved in the database if they doesn't exist. It work successfully. But the problem is a `ValueError` is appeared when the user enters an existing email address and enter another email at second time as it is not valid. What can I do to prevent it?

**The Error**

```
ValueError: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initialize_app() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only need to call initialize_app() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initialize_app() to give each app a unique name.
```

**The Code**

```
def send_data(self, email, password):
    import firebase_admin
    from firebase_admin import credentials
    from firebase_admin import firestore

    cred = credentials.Certificate("firestore.json")
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

    db = firestore.client()

    data = {
        "Email": email,
        "Password": password
    }

    query_email = db.collection(u'Users').where(u"Email", u"==", data["Email"]).get()
    if query_email:
        print('exist')
    else:
        print('does not exist')
        db.collection(u'Users').add(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message, the problem is with the following lines:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate("firestore.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()
```

If possible, move these lines outside of your function. You should initialize the `db` elsewhere and pass it to your function.

```
def send_data(self, email, password, db):
```